# Can go support the socket option IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT

Tags: go

I can use `setsockopt(IPPROTO_IP, IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT, 1)` with C language.
But when I try to do the same thing in golang, there is no option IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT.

Comment: It is listed in [the docs for sys/unix](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#section-readme) so I assume so.

Answer (score 1):

The `IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT` is defined in [sys/unix](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#pkg-constants)

> IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT                     = 0x18

Sample codes

```golang
syscall.SetsockoptInt(int(fd), unix.SOL_SOCKET, unix.IP_BIND_ADDRESS_NO_PORT, 1)
```